# iOS AutoLayout issue with ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, modalviewcontroller, autolayout

Hello i have an auto layout issue with `UIScrollView` and `ModalViewController`.
Here are my coding steps as sample code:

1) I have an `UIViewController` with an `UIScrollView` as `subView`

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[viewController.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIView *superView = viewController.view;
NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(superView,scrollView);

[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView(==superView)]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDict]];
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(==superView)]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDict]];
```

this works

2) i add 2 sub views to the `scrollView`

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollView addSubview:view1];


UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollView addSubview:view2];

viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,view1,view2);


[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view1(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDict]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view2(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDict]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view1(180)][view2(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDict]];


UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setTitle:@"open" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
[view2 addSubview:btn];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(openPopOver) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

this works also fine

3) I scroll to content offset y 180 that i can only see the view2

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 180) animated:YES];
```

4) I open a `ModalViewController` on the `ViewController

```
- (void)openModal{
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setTitle:@"close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
[viewController.view addSubview:btn];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopOver) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

5) when i close the `ModalViewController` my Layout on the `scrollView` didn't work it scrolls to an different content offset that i have not set. When i reset the content offset to y 180 the content size of the scrollview is wrong.

```
- (void)closeModal{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

}

I hope someone can help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `presentViewController:` method:

> This method sets the presentedViewController property to the specified view controller, **resizes that view controller’s view** and then adds the view to the view hierarchy. The view is animated onscreen according to the transition style specified in the modalTransitionStyle property of the presented view controller.

So the resizing of your view controller is intended. Well, by Apple, anyway.

One way to go about this is to log the resized view's coordinates and infer what exactly has been changed. Maybe you can adjust your constraints in a way to prevent this.

Alternatively, you could try resizing everything in the completion handler of this method.

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be a bug in iOS autolayout wrt UIScrollViews.  I was having a similar problem only in my case, I would push to a detail view, then pop back to the master view which is a UIScrollView.  Content in the scroll view would be shifted up.  Scrolling the scroll view to the top, then pushing and popping again and things would be properly reset.

I even tried plain out of the box master detail app using a UIScrollView instead of a table view as master, and was able to demonstrate the defect.

Table views and Collection views do not seem to have this problem.

Comment: I've seen this exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can reset the contentoffset in the `viewWillAppear`?
And did you already implement `-(void)layoutsubviews`?

Comment: this was my first idea to reset the contentoffset in the viewWill Appear but i set the contentoffset to y 180 it would not work.

Comment: yeah you're right, sorry about that. Although you could try to make a custom UIView with layoutsubviews and see if it works better that way. I personally like to always do that. Anyway, is it really a popover you're showing? Because the method says openPopOver but I don't see any code about a popovercontroller?

Comment: no sorry that was a sample code that i have written with copy paste the methods are wrong named

Comment: so i have renamed the methods

Comment: ah ok. Well can you track the uiscrollview content offset? Did you implement the scrollviewdidscroll method? Do a log there for the contentoffset and see when it changes.

Comment: that was an good idea i have add an observer to scrollView.contentOffset and it was changed to y 180 when i open the modalViewController but the content offset is alredy 180.

Comment: so i have found an compromise solution. when the viewController didDisappear was called i set the scrollView.contentOffset to y 0 and when the viewController viewDidAppear i set the contentOffset back to y 180 that would work