# iOS presentViewController breaks autolayout

Tags: ios8, autolayout

I have a TableView on top of a ViewController.

[image]

When I tap a row, I load a PDF Reader using:

```
ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
readerViewController.delegate = self; // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self
readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

But when I come back, my layout seems to be broken:

[image]

I have tried solutions like:

[Frame doesn't reflect auto layout constraints after dismissing modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997279/frame-doesnt-reflect-auto-layout-constraints-after-dismissing-modal-view-contro)

[iOS AutoLayout issue with ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509265/ios-autolayout-issue-with-scrollview)

But I can't still solve my issue. What do you recommend? Thanks

Comment: Have you check out these properties:    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets、  edgesForExtendedLayout